# Mule ESB: Getting rid of XML spaces in Groovy Output

Tags: xml, groovy, mule

I am performing logic in Groovy Script in Mule to populate XML. As part of this I am grabbing values stored in flow variables & further using them in Groovy to update XML. However I find that when I put in these values. I find that extra spaces get appended to the output. This is the output:

```
    <Address1>4375 WEST 1980 SOUTH            </Address1>
    <Address2>                                </Address2>
    <Address3>                                </Address3>
    <CityName>SALT LAKE CITY           </CityName>
```

I want it to appear without any spaces in the output as in:

```
    <Address1>4375 WEST 1980 SOUTH</Address1>
    <Address2></Address2>
    <Address3></Address3>
    <CityName>SALT LAKE CITY</CityName>
```

for your reference here is my code:

```
    <set-variable doc:name="address1" value="#[message.payload[0].Address1]"  variableName="address1"></set-variable> 
    <set-variable doc:name="address2" value="#[message.payload[0].Address2]" variableName="address2"></set-variable> 
    <set-variable doc:name="address3" value="#[message.payload[0].Address3]" variableName="address3"></set-variable>
    <set-variable doc:name="city" value="#[message.payload[0].City" variableName="city"></set-variable>

     <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[//parse
                                                  records = new      XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(payload)


                                                  info = records.Infos.Info.find { e -> e.InfoType.text().equals('Addr') }

                                                  //set data
                                                  info.Address1.replaceBody(flowVars['address1'])
                                                  info.Address2.replaceBody(flowVars['address2'])
                                                  info.Address3.replaceBody(flowVars['address3'])
                                                  info.CityName.replaceBody(flowVars['city'])
```

Would really appreciate your input.

-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sharing your payload, but I think that's where the spaces come from. Run trim on the variables if you can not fix the payload:

```
value="#[payload[0].Address1.trim()]"
```

or

```
flowVars['address1'].trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically from response you would need to trim the extra spaces, you can simply achieve this by adding below code at the end of the flow:

```
<response>
   <expression-transformer expression="org.mule.util.StringUtils.trim(payload)" doc:name="ToUpper"/>
</response>
```